# Mapbox GL JS: Display map labels above layer?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Mapbox GL JS, with a Mapbox Streets base layer. I have added a polygon layer with white borders and a transparent fill, but I'm finding it hard to read the basemap labels underneath the polygon layer. See how the labels are covered by the white borders:

[image]

Is there any way I can make sure the labels are on top of the polygon layer, or at least not obscured by it?

My code looks like this:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-2.839, 54.579],
    zoom: 4
});
map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource('constituencies', {
        'type': 'vector',
        'url': 'mapbox://pcsu.xxx'
    });
    var constituencyLayer = map.addLayer({
        'id': 'constituencies',
        'source': 'constituencies',
        'source-layer': 'constituencies',
        'type': 'fill',
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': 'rgba(162,181,205,0.6)',
            'fill-outline-color': 'white'
        },
        'layout': {
            'visibility': 'visible'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [this Mapbox example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-layer-in-stack/) and use [the second argument](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map#addLayer) of `map.addLayer(layer, [before])`. If this layer `before` exists, the new layer will be placed before/below it. I think the argument naming is a bit confusing here.

The name of the lowest label layer depends on the style. Most of the time you're looking for `housenum-label`. There's also a discussion in the [Mapbox github issues](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4173) how to ease this process, e.g by introducing placeholder layers.

Comment: Thanks - yes I'd seen the example but was confused by it, as you say (I don't understand where the `water` argument comes from in the example). In my example, there's only one layer, the constituency layer. Do I need to name the labels layer somehow? I tried just adding `, 'housenum-label'` as a final argument to `addLayer` but it hasn't helped.

Comment: Ah no, am being an idiot - adding `, 'housenum-label'` as a final argument to `addLayer` actually did solve the problem! Thanks.

Comment: I don't suppose you know how to make `housenum-label` invisible for the purposes of click events? It's now interfering with click events on the layer beneath it.

Comment: @Richard IIRC the click handler should return an array of things that are located where the click happened. If you want to filter these results given the ID of your layer, you can do so. I suspect the default order is probably the same as the visual order.